# Get each child value from each parent value while iterating with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, each, children

I want to find values of each child input hidden from iterating all checked checkbox inputs. So for each value of checkbox that I am iterate I want to find value of each input hidden in the same time
like below:

```js
function submitBTN() {
  var input_parent_grouped = [];
  var input_child_grouped = [];
  $.each($("input[name='input_parent']:checked"), function(){
      input_parent_grouped.push($(this).val());
      input_child_grouped.push($(this).children(".input_child").val()); 
  });
  console.log(input_parent_grouped);
  console.log(input_child_grouped);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="input_parent" name="input_parent" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" class="input_child" name="input_child" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="input_parent" name="input_parent" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" class="input_child" name="input_child" value="1">  
    <input type="checkbox" class="input_parent" name="input_parent" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" class="input_child" name="input_child" value="2"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="submitBTN()">Save</button>
  </div>
```

In this way input_child_grouped have undefined values all.

Comment: All the elements are siblings.  There are no children, from the DOM standpoint, with relation to your inputs.

Comment: The `.next('.input_child')` would get you the child, if starting at the "parent"

Comment: @Taplar Ah ok, and how to get values of hidden inputs in the same time from checked checkbox inputs? How to solve?

Comment: My second comment.

Comment: @Taplar It's done. Thank you very much :)

Comment: in case you have solved the problem you can add answer with solution and accept it to help people with similar problem in future :)